# Cable came loose and pc gives error now

Tags: windows, boot

People brought a computer here and the pc gives following boot error:

"Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key"

I checked the computer from the inside and the cable from an SSD was loose. Fixed that problem but still the computer gives me that error. I know of the MBR fixes and stuff. But I don't know what windows was running on the device. The people who brought the device doesn't know it either because it was from a person who passed away.

So how can I fix this MBR? I've read you need to know the exact windows version, but I don't know how to find this out?

kind regards,

EDIT: I found another SSD ( he has al lot of HDD's ) I plugged it in too now it gives me the error "missing operating system"

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate:

- You have a PC which POSTs and starts to boot windows. Ergo the disk it boots from is connected. It has a working boot sector. It starts the bootloader. **There is no need to fix a MBR**.
- It also has at least one SSD disconnected for unknown reasons.
- You can not ask the owner for information.

I am also assuming that there is no need to boot this PC to a working OS, but that you just want to look at the data on it and possibly rescue some of it. (e.g. copy family pictures and hand them over to the family).

That leaves you with a few options:

1. Get a working PC. Connect the disks one by one via an external case, or via an internal SATA port.  Look what is on the disk. Write that down or copy it. Repeat for all disks.
2. Try to get this PC working and then look at it.

Without any background information on the PC I would always choose the first option.

If you are going for the second option: The error seems to indicate a disk location or a driver problem. To work around that, boot from different media and mount the disks. A live CD would be useful here (e.g. Hirens, Knoppix, ... depending on what you are familiar with).

Comment: I think I found the problem. He has a Raid 0 I guess...

Answer (score 1):

O dear...

The fact that 1 drive was out of the machine and the other dis-connected might be an indication that the system was already in an unusuable state to begin with.
(Why would anybody make a raid0 out of 2 SSD's ?)

It could very well be you received a PC that was in the middle of an experimentation project by the previous owner.
(The fact you mentioned he had a lot of drives lying around seems to indicate he was messing about with computers a lot.)

If both SSD's are identical, these are probable both halves of the RAID0.
Connect them both to SATA0 and SATA1 and try to boot.
If that doesn't work swap the drives. It might matter if which order they are connected.

If that fails: Do what Hennes suggested and try all the drives in another system or with a LiveCD and see what you can recover.
(Basically threat this in the same way as you would recover files from a system completely hosed by a virus or a corrupted boot disk: Just get the data of if possible. )

Comment: Sweet performance rig, or more money than sense...

Comment: Is it possible that the bios changed the state to AHCI because of the loose HD?

Comment: That would be odd, but I've seen stranger things happen. AHCI is actually strongly recommended for SSD's. If the Bios has a RAID option (next to AHCI and IDE) try that too. That would make more sense if it is indeed a RAID set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to couple the drives to my own computer and see if I can recover something.

Don't going to search further for any solution for the raid to rebuild or recover...